# Uploading images to different sections of document using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to upload multiple images using the paperclip gem but I have been confronted with this error when I inserted a `link_ to` tag into the `index.html.haml` file. below is the code in each of the files for your pursual.

**index.html.haml**

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = link_to (image_tag tag.image.url(:medium)), tag
    %h2= link_to tag.title, tag
```

**Error Message**

> NameError in Tags#index undefined local variable or method `haml_temp'
>   for #<#:0x83c728dc> Did you mean?  haml_tag

Comment: You are incorrectly nesting the elements please check

Answer (score 0):

Test with this code

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = link_to tag do
    = image_tag tag.image.url(:medium)
    %h2= link_to tag.title, tag
```